# How to copy files of particular date from one path to another path in Unix

Tags: files, cp, timestamps

I want to copy a files of particular date from one directory to another directory. Can anyone suggest me the Unix command for that ?

Comment: Can you narrow down your question with example dates and directories?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this kind of operation is using the `find` command. It has lots of approaches; I will explain two of these:

1) **Relative Time Intervals**
In this approach, you can specify exactly the begin and end timestamps and than filter out every file not `modified/accessed/changed` during that period.  You can do that using the `touch` command, saving a file with a particular *timestamp*.
In the next example we create two markers (`timestamp_begin_file` and `timestamp_end_file`), set to `3 HOURS AGO` and `1 HOUR AGO`. Then we user the `newerct` and `! newerct` options to select files *newer* then 3 hours and *not newer* then 1 hour (we just take a look at `change` time in this example). All files selected will be copied in `$DESTINATION_PATH` folder.

```
touch -t $(date -d '3 HOUR AGO' +%Y%m%d%H%M.%S) timestamp_begin_file
touch -t $(date -d '1 HOUR AGO' +%Y%m%d%H%M.%S) timestamp_end_file
find "$FOLDER" -newerct timestamp_begin_file ! -newermt timestamp_end_file -exec cp {} $DESTINATION_PATH \;
```

2) **Absolute Time Intervals**
You can use `newermt` options to filter out files you don't need in a specific interval of dates. Here we select only files modified during the day of `2007-06-07`:

```
find . -type f -newermt 2007-06-07 ! -newermt 2007-06-08 -exec cp {} $DESTINATION_PATH \;
```

As I said, lots of other alternatives exist (as @Jaleks suggested, `-a/m/ctime`, too, but due to lack of information, we cannot know which case fits for you).

For more info about *time filtering* in `find`, take a look at the [manpage of find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the manpage of `find`, which has parameters like `-atime`, `-mtime` or `-ctime` to find files which got accessed, modified or changed at some given time, then you can further use the `-exec` option to copy these files.